# Sorting list of filename and folders

Tags: powershell

Looking for some help with a script I'm trying to create. 
I have a script that asks a user to enter some text (from an email) via a textbox using Winforms. This email contains a list of files and folders.
I use some regex to strip out what is not needed from the email and am left with a variable (called $results) that looks like this:

```
$results
file1.zip
graphics\folder1
file2.zip
graphics\folder1
file3.zip
graphics\folder2
etc...
```

The idea is that I now need to:

```
Extract file1.zip into graphics\folder1
Extract file2.zip into graphics\folder1
Extract file3.zip into graphics\folder2
...and so on.
```

I am trying to now create a custom PSObject so that I can call this list later in the script to deploy the files into the correct paths. I'm having a hard time trying to figure out how I can accomplish this. So far, I have tried:

```
$Object = New-Object -TypeName psobject
$Object | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name File -Value $results[0]
$Object | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Path -Value $results[1]
$Object
```

Which gives me a result of:

```
File       Path
----       ----
file1.zip  graphics\folder1
```

When I try to iterate through each item in the $results variable...

```
$Object = New-Object -TypeName psobject
forEach ($i in $results) {
$Object | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name File -Value $i[0]
$Object | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Path -Value $i[1]
}
$Object
```

...I get the following error:

```
Add-Member : Cannot add a member with the name "File" because a member with that name already exists. To overwrite the member anyway, add the Force parameter to your command.
```

I don't want to over-write, I want to append.
The problem is I am not sure how to tell PowerShell to go through each item in the $results variable and add it so that I am left with:

```
File       Path
----       ----
file1.zip  graphics\folder1
file2.zip  graphics\folder1
file3.zip  graphics\folder2
```

Once I have that, the end result is that I can take the results in the PSObject and then extract the files accordingly.

Any idea on what I am doing wrong here? 
Maybe I am going about this all wrong? 
Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Why are you using a PSCustomObject?  This is basically what hash tables exist for.

Comment: I agree with @TheIncorrigible1 - You can use a hashtable. (The reason you are getting the error is exactly what the error message says.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your example, here's what I think you're *trying* to accomplish:

Setup:

```
PS C:\> $Results
file1.zip
graphics\folder1
file2.zip
graphics\folder1
file3.zip
graphics\folder2
```

Logic:

```
$Files = @{} #initializes empty hashtable

$tmp = ''
For ($i = 0; $i -le $Results.Count; $i++)
{
    If ($i -eq 0) { $tmp = $Results[$i]; Continue } #initializes tmp value

    If ($i % 2 -eq 0) { $tmp = $Results[$i] }
    Else { $Files["$tmp"] = $Results[$i] }
}
```

Output:

```
PS C:\> $Files

Name                           Value
----                           -----
file1.zip                      graphics\folder1
file3.zip                      graphics\folder2
file2.zip                      graphics\folder1
```

Comment: Yes! This is very close to what I am looking for! I'm trying to actually be able to use each object separately however. With this example, I see the list finally but I am not able to, for example, Copy-Item $files.Name $files.Value. Does this make sense?

Comment: @obs0lete You can access a string array of keys/values by using `$Files.Keys` or `$Files.Values` and iterate over them. or something like `ForEach ($File in $Files.Keys) { Copy-Item $File $Files[$File] }`

Comment: Thanks again for the input. One last question if I may. The output is not preserving the order of the input. How would I be able to keep this?

Comment: Ok, think I got it. I added $files = [ordered]@{}  which seems to have worked.

Comment: @obs0lete Correct. Default hashtables do not keep order, what you're doing is creating an ordered dictionary there.

Answer (score 0):

```
$Object = forEach ($i in $results) {
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        File = $i[0]
        Path = $i[1]
    } 
}
$Object
```